# BigQuery - Nested Query with different WHERE parameters?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to trying to fetch the user_counts and new_user_counts by date where new_user_counts is defined by condition WHERE date of timestamp event_timestamp = date of timestamp user_first_touch_timestamp while user_counts would fetch the distinct count of user_pseduo_id field between the same date range. How can I do this in the same query? Here's how my current query is looking.

Eventually, I'd like the result to be as:

```
|Date     | new_user_count |       user_counts |
|20200820 |       X        |                 Y |
```

Here is the error I'm getting at line 8 of code:
Syntax error: Function call cannot be applied to this expression. Function calls require a path, e.g. a.b.c() at [8:5]

Thanks.

```sql
    SELECT
    event_date,
    COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS new_user_counts FROM
    `my-google-analytics-table-name.*`
    WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp))
    AND event_date BETWEEN '20200820' AND '20200831'
    (SELECT
    COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS user_counts 
    FROM `my-google-analytics-table-name.*`
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN '20200820' AND '20200831'
    )
    GROUP BY event_date
    ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what is "wrong" with you current query? does it produces wrong result or ...??? please give more details

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. I've updated the thread now with the error Syntax error: Function call cannot be applied to this expression. Function calls require a path, e.g. a.b.c() at [8:5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below (solely based on your original query just fixing the syntax/logic)

```
SELECT
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)), 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    NULL
  )) AS new_user_counts, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS user_counts 
FROM `my-google-analytics-table-name.*`
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. I've updated the question with two screenshots that show the different formats for the fields. The revised query that you just posted works for pulling the new user count by date. In my original query, the nested portion of the query wants to extract the total user count for the same dates and then show the three columns: date/new user count/ total user count

Comment: see updated answer - i think i fixed your query to produce expected result

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. That worked. I hope you don't mind the follow up questions but I'm wondering if the same query would work with a CASE function as well? If yes, what would be the advantage of the current structure over CASE? Thanks for being so helpful on SO.

Comment: hard to answer within the comment and without having details  - please post new question with all relevant details and I will answer